# Django simple upload function

Tags: python, django, file-upload, upload, django-file-upload

Getting this error:

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'save'
```

When trying to have a Django function as simple as:

```
def upload(request):
    file = request.FILES["picture"]
    file.save("hello.png")
    return HttpResponse("done uploading")
```

**Note: I know there is a longer way to make this simple procedure but I need it for now to be as simple as this one**

Answer (score 0):

You can read the uploaded file in chunks and write to your desired file, [see the documentation for details](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads)

```
def upload(request):
    file = request.FILES['picture']
    with open('hello.png', 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in file.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
    return HttpResponse('done uploading')
```